# Mass editing to change generic example URLs

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently, a user started to submit a series of edit suggestions that change the TLD `.com` to `.example` in generic URLs used in console command examples (see e.g. [this edit suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/416339)). In many cases, this was the only (visible) change to the original post, so the "edit volume" seems to be even lower than in [this related question on "minor mass edits"](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3704/377345).

Is there any consensus on how to handle this kind of edits?

P.S. Just to be clear - I do not want to imply that I consider the user to be out for cheap reputation-hunting, there are enough examples of edits that make clear improvements to posts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing `.com` to `.example` seems like, at best, a neutral change and at worst a bad one since it is changing a standard and immediately recognizable domain to one that is not even easily recognizable. Changing `foo.com` to `example.com` might make sense, but I feel that changing `foo.com` to `foo.example` is just confusing.

If that is the *only* change, I would reject the edit. However, I had a quick look at some of the other pending edits of this user and they often also include other fixes so in those cases, you may choose to "accept and improve" and just undo the `.com` => `.example` change.

Comment: It might be worth improving the edits to use `example.com` (or `.org` or whatever), see [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/17468/revisions). `.example` isn’t a valid TLD but `example.{com,net,org,edu}` are explicitly reserved as example domains.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, exactly. That's what I meant here: "*Changing foo.com to example.com might make sense, but I feel that changing foo.com to foo.example is just confusing.*"

Comment: Right, I was thinking of your suggestion to “just undo the `.com` => `.example` change”. I’m also not sure that all that many people are aware of the special status of `example.com` & co nowadays...

Comment: *"Finally, I also want to point out that it does look like this user is honestly trying to help"*. As the user is [a veteran in stackexchange and a moderator](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/14543/stephen-ostermiller), I would change that part, adding a link to [their answer below](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5958/338177), where they explain why such edits. As it is an important edit to this answer I'm just suggesting, not editing myself, but if it's OK I can do it.

Comment: Fair enough, @schrodingerscatcuriosity. When I wrote that, I hadn't realized the user was an old hand on SE and I just didn't want them to feel attacked. That's why I added that note, to clarify that edits are welcome and the user is being helpful.

Comment: I can definitely see a value in changing valid domains to IANA reserved domains.  Especially where it is clear a domain is genuinely valid but the OP didn't realise so...  Here I refer to test dot com who had a moan on their page "We not being responsible for spam email".  I can't seem to access the domain right now so maybe the self-inflicted groupthink DDOS attack has finally taken them down.  As self inflicted as it may be, someone does actually own foo dot com!  I will therefore always edit that one to `example.com`.

Answer (score 20):

Both `example.com` and the entire top level `.example` domain are officially approved for example usage.  See the following RFCs and Wikipedia entries:

- `example.com` - [RFC 2606, section 3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-3) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)
- `.example` - [RFC 2606, section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-2) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example)

Whenever an example domain is used, it should be one of these reserved example domains.  Using a real domain name is not desired because it can:

- Bestow unwarranted SEO benefit to the domain, especially when linked, but possibly even just through a mention.
- Cause problems for the domain when it gets unwanted requests from code that uses it as an example or when web crawlers find and hit the bogus URLs.

Most Stack Exchange sites actually prohibit new and edited posts from containing many incorrectly used example domains such as "mysite" or "domain" with a real top level domain suffix. This regular expression prevents a post from being submitted if the regular expression matches:

`https?://(www\.)?(domain|xxx|xyz|abc|site|mysite|mydomain)\.(com|org|net)(?![a-z0-9\-]+|\.[a-z0-9]+)`

A moderator could check that Unix & Linux actually has this rule by visiting the [user input blocklist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/admin/blocklist).

---

I acknowledge the feedback that `example.com` is more recognizable than `some-domain.example` and I'll prefer to use it in the future.

However, there are some cases in which `example.com` isn't sufficient.  When you need to compare two domains, or when a specific keyword is needed in the domain name, `.example` domains work better.  For example, cases in which a post uses multiple domains like:

- `siteA.example`
- `siteB.example`

or

- `myserver.example`
- `myhost.example`
- `mydns.example`

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Can you explain why `siteA.example` or `myhost.example` are clearer than `siteA.com` or `myhost.net`? Since `foo.example` just doesn't look like a TLD as we're not used to seeing such long ones in the wild, even if there is an RFC recommending them, it seems like the recommendation would only make sense when writing for experts not the general public.

Comment: Sure, I've added info about that case.  Using an example domain on `.com` that isn't `example.com` is a bad thing to to.

Comment: Wow, I’d completely missed the `.example` reference in RFC 2606! Thanks for taking the time to write this up (and to edit the posts). I was under the impression that the `rel="nofollow"` applied to links on SE was sufficient to negate SEO benefits, but I guess that’s not the case, right?

Comment: `nofollow` helps, BUT: 1. Stack Exchange doesn't apply `nofollow` if the post scores high enough  2. Google announced that it doesn't always honor nofollow anymore (it will use it as a hint)  3. `nofollow` only applies to links, not to mentions.  There is a strong suspicion that mentions are important to Google's algorithm, it isn't just links that matter.

Comment: Sigh. I've been a mod for 8 years almost to the day and I'd never seen that `/blocklist` page you linked to! I will console myself with the fact that you've been a mod for a year longer and that's why you know it :P.

Comment: @terdon It's listed in the "links" section of the mod dashboard, but since the moderators can't actually make any changes to the blocklist, it is an information-only page and not one that you would typically need to know about.

Comment: IANA reserves `example.com` and `example.org`.  Is that not sufficient for domain matching examples?  https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

Comment: @PhilipCouling The RFCs from the IANA there also list the entire `.example` TLD.  There are plenty of posts that need more nuance than `example.com` and `example.org` can provide. `client.example` and `server.example`; or `mysite.example` vs `othersite.example`; also cases which need to compare three or more different example domains.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You may not be wrong.  I've personally not come across a case where this was not an obviously fixable issue with subdomains `foo.example.com` `bar.example.org` `bob.example.org`.  But hey, I can't speak for the examples you've seen.  I certainly wouldn't reject an edit that changes foo dot com to `foo.example` just because one of them has publicly available DNS records pointing to a HTTP server and the other is IANA reserved.

Comment: Subdomains work sometimes too, but there are certainly issues with cookies and CORS that work differently with subdomains. That may come up less on Unix and Linux than on other stacks like Webmasters where I'm more active.

Comment: Browsers treat domains and subdomains differently in terms permissions. They have a list of what levels you're allowed to register and make security decisions at that level. So for example a subdomain can read cookies of the main domain but two separate domains can't read each other's cookies.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller purely from a point of curiosity...  The hierarchy rule makes sense. Under what context might the rule apply laterally.  Can one subdomain read another subdomain's cookies?

Comment: Subdomains have the option of setting a cookie at the domain level where it can be read by other subdomains, but they also have the option of limiting the cookie scope to just the subdomain. URL paths have similar cookie functionality.  You can set a cookie to apply to the whole domain or just to sub-directories of the current path.